# Using FileHelpers.Dynamic, read a fixed-width file and upload to SQL

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Okay, I'll try to explain this as best as I can.  I wrote an application that uses a SQL table to define a fixed-width datasource structure (so, header, start index, field length, etc).  When my application runs, it queries this table and creates a DataTable object (call it `finalDT`) with DataColumn objects holding ColumnName = header.  I then append to this table a set of DataColumn objects that exist in every datasource we use (which I tend to call derived columns).  I also create a Primary Key field that is an auto-incrementing integer.  Originally, I rolled my own solution to read the fixed-width file, but am trying to convert this to using FileHelper.  Mainly, I'm looking to incorporate it so I can have access to the other file types that FileHelper can parse (CSV, Excel, etc).

Now, my problem.  Using FileHelper.Dynamic, I was able to create a FileHelperEngine object using the following method:

```
private static FileHelperEngine GetFixedWidthFileClass(bool ignore)
{
    singletonArguments sArgs = singletonArguments.sArgs;
    singletonSQL sSQL = singletonSQL.sSQL;
    List<string> remove = new List<string>();

    FixedLengthClassBuilder flcb = new FixedLengthClassBuilder(sSQL.FixedDataDefinition.DataTableName);
    flcb.IgnoreFirstLines = 1;
    flcb.IgnoreLastLines = 1;
    flcb.IgnoreEmptyLines = true;

    foreach (var dcs in sSQL.FixedDataDefinition.Columns)
    {
        flcb.AddField(dcs.header, Convert.ToInt32(dcs.length), "String");

        if (ignore && dcs.ignore)
        {
            flcb.LastField.FieldValueDiscarded = true; //If we want to ignore a column, this is how to do it.  Would like to incorporate this.
            flcb.LastField.Visibility = NetVisibility.Protected;
        }
        else
        {
            flcb.LastField.TrimMode = TrimMode.Both;
            flcb.LastField.FieldNullValue = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    return new FileHelperEngine(flcb.CreateRecordClass());
}
```

`sSQL.FixedDataDefinition.Columns` is how I store the field definitions for the fixed-width datasource file.  I then generate a DataTable by doing:

```
DataTable dt = engine.ReadFileAsDT(file);
```

where `file` is the full path to the fixed-width file and `engine` is where I keep the results from the `GetFixedWidthFileClass()` method shown above.  Okay, now I have a DataTable with no primary key and none of the derived columns.  Also, all of the fields in `dt` are marked as `ReadOnly = true`.  Here is where things become a mess.

I need to stuff `dt` into `finalDT` and it needs to be okay with `dt` not having any Primary Key information.  If that can happen, then I can use `finalDT` to upload my data into my SQL table.  If that can't happen, then I need a way for `finalDT` to not have a Primary Key, yet still upload to my SQL table.  Will `SqlBulkCopy` allow this?  Is there another way?

At this point, I'm willing to start from scratch so long as I can use FileHelper to parse the fixed-width file and the results are stored into my SQL table, I'm just not seeing the path there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  It isn't pretty, but here is how it works.  Basically, how I setup my code in my original post still applies since I changed nothing in the `GetFixedWidthFileClass()` method.  I then had to add two methods to get `finalDT` setup correctly:

```
/// <summary>
///     For a given a datasource file, add all rows to the DataSet and collect Hexdump data 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ds">
///     The <see cref="System.Data.DataSet" /> to add to 
/// </param>
/// <param name="file">
///     The datasource file to process 
/// </param>
internal static void GenerateDatasource(ref DataSet ds, ref FileHelperEngine engine, DataSourceColumnSpecs mktgidSpecs, string file)
{
    // Some singleton class instances to hold program data I will need.
    singletonSQL sSQL = singletonSQL.sSQL;
    singletonArguments sArgs = singletonArguments.sArgs;

    try
    {
        // Load a DataTable with contents of datasource file.
        DataTable dt = engine.ReadFileAsDT(file);

        // Clean up the DataTable by removing columns that should be ignored.
        DataTableCleanUp(ref dt, ref engine);

        // ReadFileAsDT() makes all of the columns ReadOnly. Fix that.
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            column.ReadOnly = false;

        // Okay, now get a Primary Key and add in the derived columns.
        GenerateDatasourceSchema(ref dt);

        // Parse all of the rows and columns to do data clean up and assign some custom
        // values. Add custom values for jobID and serial columns to each row in the DataTable.
        for (int row = 0; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            string version = string.Empty; // The file version
            bool found = false; // Used to get out of foreach loops once the required condition is found.

            // Iterate all configured jobs and add the jobID and serial number to each row
            // based upon match.
            foreach (JobSetupDetails job in sSQL.VznJobDescriptions.JobDetails)
            {
                // Version must match id in order to update the row. Break out once we find
                // the match to save time.
                version = dt.Rows[row][dt.Columns[mktgidSpecs.header]].ToString().Trim().Split(new char[] { '_' })[0];
                foreach (string id in job.ids)
                {
                    if (version.Equals(id))
                    {
                        dt.Rows[row][dt.Columns["jobid"]] = job.jobID;

                        lock (locklist)
                            dt.Rows[row][dt.Columns["serial"]] = job.serial++;

                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (found)
                    break;
            }

            // Parse all columns to do data clean up.
            for (int column = 0; column < dt.Columns.Count; column++)
            {
                // This tab character keeps showing up in the data. It should not be there,
                // but customer won't fix it, so we have to.
                if (dt.Rows[row][column].GetType() == typeof(string))
                    dt.Rows[row][column] = dt.Rows[row][column].ToString().Replace('\t', ' ');
            }
        }

        dt.AcceptChanges();

        // DataTable is cleaned up and modified. Time to push it into the DataSet.
        lock (locklist)
        {
            // If dt is writing back to the DataSet for the first time, Rows.Count will be
            // zero. Since the DataTable in the DataSet does not have the table schema and
            // since dt.Copy() is not an option (ds is referenced, so Copy() won't work), Use
            // Merge() and use the option MissingSchemaAction.Add to create the schema.
            if (ds.Tables[sSQL.FixedDataDefinition.DataTableName].Rows.Count == 0)
                ds.Tables[sSQL.FixedDataDefinition.DataTableName].Merge(dt, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
            else
            {
                // If this is not the first write to the DataSet, remove the PrimaryKey
                // column to avoid duplicate key values. Use ImportRow() rather then .Merge()
                // since, for whatever reason, Merge() is overwriting ds each time it is
                // called and ImportRow() is actually appending the row. Ugly, but can't
                // figure out another way to make this work.
                dt.PrimaryKey = null;
                dt.Columns.Remove(dt.Columns[0]);
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    ds.Tables[sSQL.FixedDataDefinition.DataTableName].ImportRow(dr);
            }

            // Accept all the changes made to the DataSet.
            ds.Tables[sSQL.FixedDataDefinition.DataTableName].AcceptChanges();
        }

        // Clean up memory.
        dt.Clear();

        // Log my progress.
        log.GenerateLog("0038", log.Info
                        , engine.TotalRecords.ToString() + " DataRows successfully added for file:\r\n\t"
                        + file + "\r\nto DataTable "
                        + sSQL.FixedDataDefinition.DataTableName);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Something bad happened here.
        log.GenerateLog("0038", log.Error, "Failed to add DataRows to DataTable "
                        + sSQL.FixedDataDefinition.DataTableName
                        + " for file\r\n\t"
                        + file, e);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Successful or not, get rid of the datasource file to prevent other issues.
        File.Delete(file);
    }
}
```

And this method:

```
/// <summary>
///     Deletes columns that are not needed from a given <see cref="System.Data.DataTable" /> reference.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dt">
///     The <see cref="System.Data.DataTable" /> to delete columns from. 
/// </param>
/// <param name="engine">
///     The <see cref="FileHelperEngine" /> object containing data field usability information. 
/// </param>
private static void DataTableCleanUp(ref DataTable dt, ref FileHelperEngine engine)
{
    // Tracks DataColumns I need to remove from my temp DataTable, dt.
    List<DataColumn> removeColumns = new List<DataColumn>();

    // If a field is Discarded, then the data was not imported because we don't need this
    // column. In that case, mark the column for deletion by adding it to removeColumns.
    for (int i = 0; i < engine.Options.Fields.Count; i++)
        if (engine.Options.Fields[i].Discarded)
            removeColumns.Add(dt.Columns[i]);

    // Reverse the List so changes to dt don't generate schema errors.
    removeColumns.Reverse();

    // Do the deletion.
    foreach (DataColumn column in removeColumns)
        dt.Columns.Remove(column);

    // Clean up memory.
    removeColumns.Clear();
}
```

Basically, since `ds` (the DataSet where `finalDT` lives) was referenced in the `GenerateDatasource` method, I could not use `dt.Copy()` to push data into it.  I had to use `Merge()` to do this.  Then, where I would have liked to use `Merge()`, I had to use a `foreach` loop and `ImportRow()` because `Merge()` was overwriting `finalDT`.

Other issues I had to fix were:

1. When I use `ImportRow()`, then I also need to delete the `PrimaryKey` from `dt` or else I get errors about duplicate keys.
2. `FileHelperEngine` or `FileHelpers.Dynamic.FixedLengthClassBuilder` has a problem with jumping past columns I want to ignore.  It either won't acknowledge them at all, thus killing my column offset and, subsequently, the accuracy on how data is read in the datasource file (using the `FieldHidden` option) or it reads them and creates the column in anyhow, but doesn't load the data (using the `FieldValueDiscarded` and `Visibility.Private` or `.Protected` options).  What this means for me is I had to iterate `dt` after the call to `engine.ReadFileAsDT(file)` and delete columns marked as `Discarded`.
3. Since FileHelper knows nothing about my PrimaryKey column or the other derived columns that are added to all of my datasources during processing, I had to pass `dt` to a method (`GenerateDatasourceSchema()`) to sort that out.  That method basically just adds these columns and ensures the PrimaryKey is the first column.

The rest of the code is fix up I need to do to columns and rows.  In some cases, I'm setting values for a column for each row, in others, I'm cleaning up errors in the original data (as it comes to me from my customer).

It's not pretty and I hope to figure out a better way down the road.  If anyone has input on how I did it, I would love to hear it.